# 403 forbidden for some youtube urls

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Currently I am developing an app which fetches audio url from a youtube video id.
It is working perfectly for some url and not working at all for some urls.
Even I copied in a browser to play a audio url,One url worked other didnot.
For your information I am using Mytoolkit.Multimedia  to fetch audio urls.
For example-
This url works-
https://r13---sn-h557sn7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&mn=sn-h557sn7y&mm=31&pl=24&mime=audio/mp4&id=o-ACVoF4mkT7VFETu-c1pUD-2y3fiDbqhg_AWvjzMh6rLd&gir=yes&mt=1486618643&ms=au&requiressl=yes&ip=103.6.159.152&upn=ck_2dMVCbO0&signature=C65C13CAE27021FA797E07C3C957F2106FA43F0C.542B383152E7D32AD7F5C3C386D7D7E4CCB7C846&lmt=1458210574977365&key=yt6&itag=140&keepalive=yes&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,upn,expire&source=youtube&clen=4324664&initcwndbps=551250&ei=SgCcWKXHDM3ioAOdy6PgCA&mv=m&dur=272.230&expire=1486640298

This url does not work-
https://r9---sn-h557sn7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mn=sn-h557sn7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=103.6.159.152&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gcr,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,upn,expire&pl=24&source=youtube&dur=258.089&keepalive=yes&mv=m&gcr=in&ms=au&ei=gQCcWJyTEcS3oAPR3IjoCA&id=o-ACkoY4Axz1oHH7Ncr4llzAWZn8JoIFAtS7HTbve90Xgd&mt=1486618702&gir=yes&upn=PF_MHOBEk38&ipbits=0&mime=audio/mp4&requiressl=yes&clen=4099627&expire=1486640353&itag=140&lmt=1438240696726539&initcwndbps=551250&signature=1CDC7B591477B660AEF655DC5687F750F57C8CFF44.FB05DE5F885A99FFD0DE7B5D75AB2589C40FFF77

Also I noticed,it is not working for those whose parameter ends with signature,
I guess that does not matter.I have re-arranged parameters ,Still same error(http error 403).
Please note-Even links not working google chrome.

Is there any other ways ,where I extract audio from youtube video id.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I final built a custom library to fetch data,Problem was not with youtube links,it was with libraries I was using.

Answer (score 0):

You may find in [YouTube Data API - Errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) the possible reasons why you encounter Error 403.

Based from the given link, `error 403 - forbidden` is basically due to a not properly authorized request. Please check and make sure that you set proper authorization or make sure that the permissions associated with the requests are sufficient.

Comment: ,Thanks for replying,How the other link is working it has same parameters.And I am getting these urls after authorization.Do you have any sample ,where all the urls work.

Comment: Do you have any other ways,Where you can extract audio urls from youtube video id,I have already tried YoutubeExtractor and mytoolkit.Extended